# Which user is the website host?

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, vps, wordpress

I'm learning about servers, and I'm configuring Nginx, MySQL, PHP, and WordPress.
the server distro is Debian 6.

I created a new user and I want each user to be the owner of the site folder  `/var/www/site.one`, so I run the command `chown -R kossel:kossel site.one`

My problem is, my WordPress only works if I `chmod 644 wp-config.php`, which all can read [wordpress site suggest](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) that file should be 640.

My question is, when someone opens mydomain.com, WordPress has to access the wp-config.php file, but which user is it actually using to "read" that file? The root user? User kossel? Anyone else?  How can I properly give it permission or ownership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created a new user and I wish each user is the owner of the site
>   folder  `/var/www/site.one` so I `chown -R kossel:kossel site.one`

Why do you want to do that? The document root (`/var/www/site.one`) should owned by the user that the web server is running as (`www-data` on the Debian based, `apache` on the Red Hat based).

> my problem is, my wordpress only work if I chmod 644 wp-config.php,
>   which all can read [wordpress site suggest][1] that file should be
>   640.

Because you did wrong in the above step.

> and my question is: when someone open mydomain.com, wordpress has to
>   access wp-config.php file, but which user is it actually using to
>   "read" that file? root? user kossel? anyone else?

As I said above, that is `www-data` user. You can check this by running `ps -ef | grep nginx`.

> how can I properly give it permission or owner?

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/site.one
chmod -R 755 /var/www/site.one
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I did ps -ef | grep httpd and how the user is root instead of www-data?? 
root     32216 32202  0 04:13 pts/0    00:00:00 grep httpd
I installed nginx using root account with this script: http://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/3965/leb-setup-script-for-debian-6-vps-nginx-mysql-iptables-etc/p1

Comment: `ps -ef | grep nginx`?

Comment: root     18290     1  0 Sep12 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data 18291 18290  0 Sep12 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root     32234 32202  0 04:24 pts/0    00:00:00 grep nginx, I think this is ok. I did what you do and everything works fine now. thanks

Comment: You webserver (Nginx) is running as `www-data` user.

Comment: IMHO it should be chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/site.one. And chmod -R 755 /var/www/site.one is dirty : php files and images have no need to be executable.

Answer (score 1):

In Debian (most of the time) web server runs by 'www-data' user. If you want your website to work, its files should be readable (or executable) by www-user. So your wp-config.php is must be readable by the www-data user. In order to fix your problem you can do several things,

1. Add www-data to the group the site is owned
2. change the group ownership of the folder to www-data

By doing one of the above changes you can keep wp-connfig.php 640.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [apache-mod-mpm-itk](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/) with it you can run all websites (virtualhosts) in the name of it's owners. So 640 will be ok for wp-config.php.